# Is there a way that I can compare coefficient of the same variable in regression models baed on data of different times?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, coefficients

Supposedly I will like to compare how education affects wage at different times
I construct a regression model
wage = beta* education + a list of controlled variable+ error
Can i directly compare the beta if i generate 3 models based on data in different years?
Let's say in 2000, I have wage = 2000education, in 2010, I have wage = 1000eduation and in 2020, I have wage = 500 education
If not, what can I do to do so?
I am using R to code

I am quite new to regression model, so I only know about basic regression model and time series model.

Comment: By comapre, I mean can I say education in 2020 has a less impact on wage than 2010, and thus 2000

Comment: Why not pool the data and build a model with year as a covariate?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115262/11849